# Cordova signed apk produces a blank screen after splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, apk, signed

Cordova debug build working fine. But signing apk produces white screen after splash screen

Already tried with creating new app and signing with the release key. But the same issue on signed apk.

```
cordova version - 7.1.0 
cordova platform android -> 7.1.0
```

Here are plugins that i'm using:

```
-  cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-dialogs@~2.0.1  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-file@~6.0.1  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-geolocation@~4.0.1  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-google-analytics@~1.8.6  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@~3.0.0  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-splashscreen@~5.0.2  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-statusbar@~2.4.2  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-whitelist@~1.3.3  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing@~5.4.1  cordova plugin add
-  ionic-plugin-keyboard@~2.2.1  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-network-information@~2.0.1  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-x-toast@~2.6.2  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-customurlscheme@~4.3.0   cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-file-transfer@~1.7.1  cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-facebook4@~2.2.0   cordova plugin add
-  cordova-plugin-googleplus
```

**How I can debug signed apk? to see errors on signed apk build.
What could be the reason that produces a white screen on signing?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Most cases, it would be some plugin that is causing the issue with the target device. Now, how can you debug this

1. Load your cordova project in [Android Studio](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/)
2. [Run your project](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app) to the device directly.
3. Once the apk is installed and your cordova app is loaded, check your [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) for potential show stoppers *(will be in red)*. Once you identify the root cause, you can work on making a fix.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is error that I'm getting from logcat: 07-02 11:54:49.480 26875 26918 E chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
Any idea? what should i do now?

Comment: Can you share the snapshot of the error screen please??

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18KmrcWp-CBrFJmvDrxu5oC4QZzVLvAc_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Android Debug Bridge (ADB)?

for example, on Ubuntu terminal, you can type:

```
adb logcat chromium:D SystemWebViewClient:D *:S
```

Comment: Here is error that I'm getting from logcat:
07-02 11:54:49.480 26875 26918 E chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
07-02 11:54:49.874 26875 26918 E chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
07-02 11:54:50.130 26875 26918 E chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202

Any idea? what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

I guess It's a SSL certificate problem in server.
It will work fine in debug mode, **using expired ssl certification.**
But It will not working in Singed APK.

Check your server url to below link.
https://www.digicert.com/help/